# r data.table how to do a lookup from a different data.table

Tags: r, data.table

The code below does what I want for a simple table. The mapping that takes place in the statement with `on` works perfectly. But I also have the situation with multiple countries that need to be assigned potentially to multiple regions and the result stored in the regions column is more challenging

```
library(data.table)
testDT <- data.table(country = c("Algeria", "Egypt", "United States", "Brazil"))
testDTcomplicated <- data.table(country = c("Algeria, Ghana, Sri Lanka", "Egypt", "United States, Argentina", "Brazil"))
regionLookup <- data.table(countrylookup = c("Algeria", "Argentina", "Egypt", "United States", "Brazil", "Ghana", "Sri Lanka"), regionVal = c("Africa", "South America", "Africa", "North America", "South America", "Africa", "Asia"))
testDT[regionLookup, region := regionVal, on = c(country = "countrylookup")]
> testDT
         country        region
1:       Algeria        Africa
2:         Egypt        Africa
3: United States North America
4:        Brazil South America
```

I'd like to have testDTcomplicated look like the following

```
> testDT
             country                          region
    1:       Algeria, Ghana, Sri Lanka        Africa, Africa, Asia
    2:       Egypt                            Africa
    3: United States, Argentina, Brazil       North America, South America, South America
    4:        Brazil                          South America
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the data on comma and get each country in a separate row, join the data with  `regionLookup` and collapse them again in one value in a  comma-separated string.

```
library(data.table)

testDTcomplicated[, row := seq_len(.N)]
new <- splitstackshape::cSplit(testDTcomplicated, 'country', ',', 
        direction = 'long')[regionLookup, region := regionVal, 
         on = c(country = "countrylookup")]
new <- new[, lapply(.SD, toString), row][,row:=NULL]

new
#                     country                       region
#1: Algeria, Ghana, Sri Lanka         Africa, Africa, Asia
#2:                     Egypt                       Africa
#3:  United States, Argentina North America, South America
#4:                    Brazil                South America
```

Same logic in `dplyr` can be implemented as :

```
library(dplyr)

testDTcomplicated %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   tidyr::separate_rows(country, sep = ", ") %>%
   left_join(regionLookup, by =  c("country" = "countrylookup")) %>%
   group_by(row) %>%
   summarise(across(.fns = toString))
```

Comment: The dplyr version works for me but when I try the code with cSplit, I get `Error in new[, lapply(.SD, toString), row] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. More generally, Wow, I am constantly amazed at what people can do with R.

Comment: Sorry, auto-correct keeps correcting my variable names. It turned `regionVal` to `regional`. Can you check the updated answer now?

Comment: If you replace regional with regionVal, the first one works fine too!

Comment: Is there a way to turn off autocorrect? This happens to me too! Why should these text field try to correct code???

Comment: In my case its not SO editor that corrects the word. I have an extension enabled which does it.